# malloc 1D array in struct

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, malloc

I have a struct and I want to `malloc()` in the struct a 1D array but it doesn't let me. This is my struct.

```
//n = blabla

struct memory {

    int *results;
    results = malloc(n * sizeof(int));      
    int side;

} *pmemOUT;
```

The error is "expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'results'" but I don't really get what that means. I read on the internet that this error means that I use something before I declare it but I still can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Also, note that you should decide whether you are writing C or C++ code, because the answers are different depending on which language you're using.  If you're writing in C, then you simply can't put executable code in the middle of a structure definition like that.  If you're writing C++, you shouldn't be using `malloc()` in the first place (use `new` instead), and the allocation would be done in a constructor with an argument telling you how many elements to allocate (and you should record how many elements were allocated, too).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot allocate memory inside the struct (in fact, you cannot have any statements except member type declarations inside the struct declaration). Either use a constructor (C++), or allocate the memory for the `results` pointer outside the struct declaration, like

```
// this statement must be outside the struct definition
pmemOUT->results = malloc(n* sizeof(int));
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n = 16;
struct memory {
    int *results;
    int side;
} *pmemOUT;

int main()
{
    pmemOUT = (struct memory*)malloc(sizeof(struct memory)); /* allocate memory for the struct */
    pmemOUT->results = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int)); /* allocate memory for its member */    
    pmemOUT->results[0] = 10; /* assign something */
    printf("%d\n", pmemOUT->results[0]); /* test that it worked */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So results still works as an array. I am just allocating the memory outside of the struct. Right?

Comment: yes, `results` is a pointer (so it behaves like an array), and you just declare it in the struct. You then allocate its memory outside.

Comment: and how can i change the value of this member? I mean pmemOUT->results[0] = value is wrong.